# Change the css of a div when a specific image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three images and depending on which image is clicked I want to change the css of a specific div. I just don't understand how to connect the click of an image to the div.

Below is a (bad) example of how I think it should work. I don't understand how this is accomplished without creating a function for each image/click.

```
 $('.circle_hiw_cont img').click(
        function() {
            if(this == content_img_1.jpg) {
                  $("#content_1").css("display", "block");
                   $("#content_2").css("display", "none"); 
                  $("#content_3").css("display", "none");
            } else {

            }
        }
    );
```

HTML:

```
<img id="content_img_1" src="images/conent_img1.jpg"/>
<img id="content_img_2" src="images/conent_img2.jpg"/>
<img id="content_img_3" src="images/conent_img3.jpg"/>
<div id="content_1">This is div 1</div>
<div id="content_2">This is div 2</div>
<div id="content_3">This is div 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content_1{display:block;}
#content_2{display:none;}
#content_3{display:none;}
```

Comment: Can you modify the HTML? If you can, you could add a `data-` value in each image with the id of the target `div` and apply the same function for all

Comment: I can edit the html and I added it to my question above it is still missing the css which just hides the other two divs. would you be able to give me a simple example? Thanks!

Comment: I see they replied 7 times while I was preparing the jsfiddle. I guess you won't be needing my answer, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/u7hmfn74/ :)

Comment: Thanks for your info. And thanks everyone for the answers. I am going to do some testing real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try

```js
var $contents = $('.content');
var $imgs = $('.circle_hiw_cont img').click(function() {
  var $target = $('#content_' + this.id.replace('content_img_', '')).show();
  $contents.not($target).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle_hiw_cont">
  <img id="content_img_1" src="//placehold.it/64/ff0000" />
  <img id="content_img_2" src="//placehold.it/64/00ff00" />
  <img id="content_img_3" src="//placehold.it/64/0000ff" />
  <div id="content_1" class="content">This is div 1</div>
  <div id="content_2" class="content">This is div 2</div>
  <div id="content_3" class="content">This is div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the example I was able to implement into my current script and it worked exactly how it should.

Answer (score 3):

You can add classes to the elements and use the `index` and `eq` methods:

```
var $img = $('.img').on('click', function() {
   $('.div').hide().eq( $img.index(this) ).show();
});
```

Note that as this solution is index-based, the order of elements matters.

Comment: I like this answer, but it assumes that the number of images and the number of divs are going to be the same, and sorted correctly; which we don't know if it's the case from the question

Comment: True. And OP actually chose an answer that follows the same line of thought (if that's the case, I personally like yours better)

Answer (score 0):

if which div is shown is predefined, that should work:

```
 $('.circle_hiw_cont img').click(
        function() {
            if( $(this).attr('src') === "content_img_1.jpg") {
                  $("#content_1, #content_2, #content_3").toggle();
            } else {

            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually weren't too far off, `this` is going to refer to the current DOM node though, not the src of the image as your code assumes:

```
$('.circle_hiw_cont img').click(
        function() {
            if(this.src == "content_img_1.jpg") {
                  $("#content_1").css("display", "block");
                   $("#content_2").css("display", "none"); 
                  $("#content_3").css("display", "none");
            } else {

            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The context `this` in the function call refers to the DOM element that was clicked. You will need to compare the appropriate attribute, instead.

```
$('.circle_hiw_cont img').click(
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.attr('href') == 'content_img_1.jpg') {
              ...
        } else {

        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Provide some class name to all the images say "imgClass" and

```
 $('.imgClass').click(
    function() {
              $("#content_1").css("display", "block");
               $("#content_2").css("display", "none"); 
              $("#content_3").css("display", "none");
                }
 );
```